# Case Select Then Insert Into Temp Table not working

Tags: sql, select, case

Im trying to get this statement to work to mine some text in a freetext fields...

```
SELECT
CASE
     WHEN Theme_Q1 LIKE '%Education%' THEN
         INSERT INTO #tempThemeCnt(Theme1, ThemeCnt) VALUES ( 'Education', 1  )
     WHEN Theme_Q1 LIKE '%Care%' THEN
         INSERT INTO #tempThemeCnt(Theme1, ThemeCnt) VALUES ( 'Care', 1  )
END
FROM dbo.tblWNHPSurvey
```

Thanks you all for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT -- Updated to reflect OP's actual problem as described in comment block below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efd1b/5

This *should* work on sql server 2005 -- I have no way of testing this. Earliest version I can run it on is 2008R2. Also -- you should *totally* upgrade!

If you can't see how to refactor it to your tables post a comment but I hope it will be fairly obvious.

This uses APPLY to count references for you.

```
SELECT
    t.tag,
    ISNULL(m.matches, 0) AS Matches
FROM
  tags AS t
  OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM TestSet AS ts
     WHERE ts.Label LIKE '%' + t.tag + '%'
     )
     AS m (matches)
```

Schema used:

```
CREATE TABLE TestSet (
  TestID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Label VARCHAR(MAX)
  )

INSERT TestSet(Label)
      SELECT 'Educational Care'
UNION SELECT 'Care Failure'
UNION SELECT 'SomeRandomTextHere'
UNION SELECT 'Care Education'


CREATE TABLE Tags(
  Tag VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY
  )

INSERT Tags (Tag)
      SELECT 'Education'
UNION SELECT 'Care'
```

Results:

```
TAG         MATCHES
Care        3
Education   2
```

Notes:
This is likely to be fairly slow... the LIKE '%%' predicate has no possible index it can use.

Original answer...

case isn't a control of flow switch - its a formatter. you don't *do* something different for each case - you return something different

it would be something like this:

```
INSERT #tempThemeCnt(Theme1, ThemeCnt)
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Theme_Q1 like '%Education%' THEN 'Education'
        WHEN Theme_Q1 like '$Care%' THEN 'Care'
        ELSE Theme_Q1
    END AS Theme1,
    1 AS ThemeCnt
FROM
    dbo.tblWNHPSurvey
```

Note that its impossible to tell from your example what you wanted if the values were not mapped to Education or Care -- this example simply sticks whatever was in dbo.tblWNHPSurvey into the temp table with a ThemeCnt of 1 if it didn't match...

Also -- I suspect you may want to group this afterwards....

Comment: Hello Charlie,Yes you are correct I will group them in the end once I have all them counted. Basically, I have 40 plus keywords to match each field and count them if match. So I expect that in the end my temptable will balloon to either 5 of ten times it orginal rows. What I want to achieve is so scan every field and count every keyword it finds. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: If I understand you then I don't think this is actually what you want to do. If a line can match more than one keyword and you want that line to be counted as matching all the matched keywords then this method will not work. Each line will match to *at most* one of those case statements. Post some sample data and expected output but it sounds like this is not the solution

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: We are using SQL 2005, sadly we just migrated to 2005 from 2000. I wish to upload my sample data. Is this possible just a text file?

Comment: You could add it as an example like I did in my answer (into a temp table or so) -- or use sqlfiddle (which seems to be down right now). I ammended my answer to reflect your requirements. Comment if it is confusing -- this uses some new syntax (from 2005 onwards) that you may not be familiar with.

Comment: Also if you just upgraded to 2005 you'd need the database to be in the right compatibility mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933794.aspx

Comment: Hi @Transact Charlie, I will give this a try, and let you know. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO #tempThemeCnt(Theme1, ThemeCnt)
SELECT (CASE WHEN Theme_Q1 LIKE '%Education%' THEN 'Education' 
             WHEN Theme_Q1 LIKE '%Care%' THEN 'Care' 
             ELSE ''
        END) AS Theme1, 1   
FROM dbo.tblWNHPSurvey;
```

Comment: Wow! That was quick! :) Thanks Saharsh Shah! I realized, if I have multiple keywords in a field, it only find the the first and ignore the rest. I want to count every keyword, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly case doesn't work like that.
You could achieve this using something like the below logic:

```
if exists (select top 1 1 from dbo.tblWNHPSurvey where Theme_Q1 like '%Education%')
insert into #tempThemeCnt(Theme1, ThemeCnt) VALUES ( 'Education', 1  )

if exists (select top 1 1 from dbo.tblWNHPSurvey where Theme_Q1 like '%Care%')
insert into #tempThemeCnt(Theme1, ThemeCnt) VALUES ( 'Care', 1  )
```

Comment: NB: my answer will only create 1 education and/or 1 care record, regardless of the number of matches in the tblWNHPSurvey table.  @SaharshShah's will create one record for each match in that table.  Not sure which solution you're hoping for, so either could be correct for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you John! please refer my follow up question I added to Charlie.